# I have a question about merge sort algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I've looked at the merge sort example code, but there's something I don't understand.

```
void mergesort(int left, int right)
{
    if (left < right)
    {
        int sorted[LEN];
        int mid, p1, p2, idx;

        mid = (left + right) / 2;

        mergesort(left, mid);
        mergesort(mid + 1, right);

        p1 = left;
        p2 = mid + 1;
        idx = left;

        while (p1 <= mid && p2 <= right)
        {
            if (arr[p1] < arr[p2])
                sorted[idx++] = arr[p1++];
            else
                sorted[idx++] = arr[p2++];
        }

        while (p1 <= mid)
            sorted[idx++] = arr[p1++];

        while (p2 <= right)
            sorted[idx++] = arr[p2++];

        for (int i = left; i <= right; i++)
            arr[i] = sorted[i];
    }
}
```

In this code, I don't know about a third while loop.

In detail, This code inserts p1, p2 in order into the 'sorted array'.

I want to know how this while loop creates an ascending array.

I would appreciate it if you could write your answer in detail so that I can understand it.

Comment: Where have you got it from that a code block should be between `\` \`\`\`` and `\`\`\` \`` (spaces are next lines)?

Comment: "I don't understand why the array is sorted in ascending order." both subarrays are sorted, so it's just merging the two sorted subarrays into a larger sorted array.

Comment: @273K See [this meta thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421118/code-blocks-surrounded-by-single-backtick-then-triple-backticks).

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you for the reference to SO Meta.

Comment: What is `p1`? What is `p2`? How do they relate to the extremely friendly animation on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)?

Comment: @Useless - the animation on WIkipedia is bad, it shows a top down split, but then shows the merges in bottom up order (left to right), instead of top down's depth first, left first order. For example, the left 4 numbers should be merged before starting on the 3rd pair of numbers.

Comment: That's a fair point, although perhaps it's really only trying to show the bottom-up variant. Either way, seeing which boxes correspond to `p1` and `p2` during the merge phase is easy enough

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm a developer working in the field.
I was surprised to see you embodying merge sort.

Before we start, the time complexity of the merge sort is O(nlogn).
The reason can be found in the merge sort process!

First, let's assume that there is an unordered array.

Merger sorting process:

1. Divide it into an array of 1 size by the number of size of the array.
2. Create an array that is twice the size of the divided array.
3. Compare the elements of the two divided arrays and put the smaller elements in order in the created array.
4. Repeat this process until it reaches the size of the original array.

[merge sort img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H385.png)

There is a reason why the time complexity of the merge sort is O(nLogn).

In this process, the time complexity of log is obtained because the array is continuously divided by half, and the time complexity of nlogn is obtained because the process is performed by a total of n times.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

> why the array is sorted in ascending order

Merge sort divides an array of n elements into n runs of 1 element each. Each of those single element runs can be considered to be sorted since they only contain a single element. Pairs of single element runs are merged to create sorted runs of 2 elements each. Pairs of 2 element runs are merged to create sorted runs of 4 elements each. The process continues until a sorted run equal the size of the original array is created.

The example in the question is a top down merge sort, that recursively splits the array in half until a base case of a single element run is reached. After this, merging follows the call chain, depth first left first. Most libraries use some variation of bottom up merge sort (along with insertion sort used to detect or create small sorted runs). With a bottom up merge sort, there's no recursive splitting, an array of n elements is treated as n runs of 1 element each, and starts merging even and odd runs, left to right, in a merge pass. After ceiling(log2(n)) passes, the array is sorted.

The example code has an issue, it allocates an entire array on the stack for each level of recursion which will result in stack overflow for large arrays. The Wiki examples are better, although the bottom up example should swap references rather than copy the array.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

---

For the question's code, might as well have sorted as a global array, or at least declared as static (a single instance):

```
static int arr[LEN];
static int sorted[LEN];
void mergesort(int left, int right)
/* ... */
```

Comment: The array allocations will add up to nlogn - not optimal but probably not a killer.

Comment: @MarkRansom - if array size is greater than stack size (Visual Studio default is 1MB), the program will fail on the first level of recursion. Assuming `LEN` is a define, some compilers might report an error at compile time. I didn't check, but changing the code to `static int sorted[LEN];` (not using the stack) should work, since each recursion instance is using a different part of `sorted[]` .